# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, string, for-loop, types, operands

I'm trying to write a Python script to count down to my next birthday. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message stating

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
import datetime

birthday = input('Please enter your birthday(mm/dd/yyyy): ')
birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y').date()

currentDate = datetime.datetime.today()

days = birthday - currentDate
print(days)
```

Comment: You need to convert `birthday` as datetime object.

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: This is written in Python. I'm sorry for not stating that in the post. How do I convert it to a datetime object?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use birthdate as a datetime object, and use it instead of birthday.

```
birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y')
currentDate = datetime.datetime.today()

days = birthdate - currentDate
```